# Как присвоить переменной, значение из SQL запроса к LocalDB?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server

У меня есть таблица "Топливо" с параметрами.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Топливо] (
    [Id]       UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [Название] NCHAR (100)      NOT NULL,
    [Ron]      INT              NULL,
    [wv]       FLOAT (53)       NULL,
    [amp]      FLOAT (53)       NULL,
    [acc]      FLOAT (53)       NULL,
    [arz]      INT              NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Как мне переменным  `float  Ron, wv, amp, acc, arz` присвоить значения из таблицы `[dbo].[Топливо]`

Мой код:

```
string queryString2 = string.Format("SELECT [Ron], [wv], [amp], [acc], [arz]  FROM [dbo].[Топливо] WHERE [Id]='" + _IdRG + "'");

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ПАК_DataDataSet3.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(queryString2, connection))
            using (SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2))
            {
                try
                {
                    float Ron = "Ron";//неправильно
                    float wv = "wv";//неправильно
                    float amp = "amp";//неправильно
                    float acc = "acc";//неправильно
                    float arz = "arz";//неправильно
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так

```
string queryString2 = string.Format("SELECT [Ron], [wv], [amp], [acc], [arz]  FROM [dbo].[Топливо] WHERE [Id]='" + _IdRG + "'");

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ПАК_DataDataSet3.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(queryString2, connection))
        using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd2.executeReader())
        {
            try
            {
                while (R.Read())
                {
                    if (!dataReader.IsDBNull(0) && !dataReader.IsDBNull(1)&& !dataReader.IsDBNull(2)&& !dataReader.IsDBNull(3)&& !dataReader.IsDBNull(4))
                    {
                        float Ron = dataReader.GetFloat(0)//Можно Convert.ToFloat(dataReader["Ron"]);
                        float wv = dataReader.GetFloat(1)
                        float amp = dataReader.GetFloat(2)
                        float acc = dataReader.GetFloat(3)
                        float arz = dataReader.GetFloat(4)
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас занят другим. Как будет время, проверю и если правильно, то отмечу как правильный ответ.

Comment: @IvanTriumphov  проверили? или коллега зря старался?